# What about having a comment section on the user profile page?

Tags: feature-request, comments, jobs, profile-page

Considering careers.stackoverflow.com, employers may be intersted in seeing your questions, answers as well as your comments.

Some comments contains valuable information that can show your knowledge to a potential employer.

It could be woth the cost to add a publicy available section in user profiles, showing all comments. A new dedicated tab, or an expandable section in order not to pollute the user profile.

Most times user comments are not inteligible, when read out of context, Why not to display its whole context. That is: the related answer followed by all comments including the concerned user's comments, highlighted in a dedicated color.

As stackoverflow's main goal is dedicated to provide the best answers to questions, the adding of this feature could boost the comments quality and indirectly enhance answers quality, and prevent it from being used as chat room , as it could pollute the comment section in your public profile. SO users might be more prone to delete their unvaluable commments as a consequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments on user profiles? My mind reels at the number of ways this could go horribly, horribly wrong.

We try to keep the focus on the *content*, not the user.

Comment: Actually, i think he's talking about comments *made by* users (like the one i'm writing right now) not comments *on* users...

Comment: @Shog9 right, that is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

Comments aren't meant to be answers, essays, or showcases for your writing skills. They're a way for you to provide feedback to other users on *their* questions or answers.

If you have something worthwhile to say... or just want to show off... then write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

SO isn't intended to be any type of discussion, so comments are just an extra feature.  It is first and foremost a question/answer site. So I think the focus should just be on questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

The possible employers have access to our SO profile, so they can search for whatever they'd like.